# Outlook not rendering emails sent

Tags: perl, email, mime-types

I'm a bit baffled by this. It works fine in everything I've tested, except Outlook

```
    my @all_parts;
    push @all_parts, Email::MIME->create(

            body_str => $text,
            attributes => {
                encoding => 'quoted-printable',
                content_type => "text/plain",
                disposition  => "inline",
                charset      => "UTF-8"
            }

    );

    my $email = Email::MIME->create(
        header_str => [
            From => $from,
            To => [ $to ],
            Subject => $subject
        ],
        parts => \@all_parts,
        attributes => {
            content_type => "multipart/mixed"
        }
    );

 print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";
 print "<pre>" . $email->as_string  . "</pre> ";
```

Which outputs this message:

```
From: delicia@x.com
To: andy.newby@hotmail.com
Subject: webform delicia Menu
Date: Sat, 21 Mar 2020 04:22:57 -0700
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="15847897770.621258BEF.22006"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


--15847897770.621258BEF.22006
Date: Sat, 21 Mar 2020 04:22:57 -0700
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

foo bar=

--15847897770.621258BEF.22006--
```

For some reason it shows up buggered:

[image]

I must be missing something really stupid - but I can't see it. Maybe a missing header?

The full source of an incoming email looks like:

```
Return-path: <x@x.com>
Envelope-to: support@mysite.co.uk
Delivery-date: Sat, 21 Mar 2020 15:33:16 +0000
Received: from gt-van-cus5.nmsrv.com ([208.70.247.69])
    by admin.foo.com with esmtps (TLS1.2:ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:256)
    (Exim 4.86_2)
    (envelope-from <x@x.com>)
    id 1jFg7e-0006lZ-G5
    for support@mysite.co.uk; Sat, 21 Mar 2020 15:33:16 +0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed; d=x.com; h=message-id
    :from:to:subject:date:mime-version:content-type
    :content-transfer-encoding; s=mail; bh=TUrwl9pmlEV+CwP8vMMqxIQa9
    Bg=; b=G2DuFVkwBF8qkCi7zM3hnwl18nkdIW83JbAoheLTAG9Xh6Ix2bxdPVsP7
    3wI1cjUDjWGhTUlMLHGKP5kHT4FPKFkhMclIv+KZ1jU65BaMjRuwWz/FkTRg7v6I
    oClvU/PXXn5gqfRiYZHR4L8qgCQaGhuXncxNgtaELqoQosU+gc=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; d=x.com; h=message-id
    :from:to:subject:date:mime-version:content-type
    :content-transfer-encoding; q=dns; s=mail; b=VHNvnP4AnMZxow+CoUj
    3Xxj5KkIWJtUOJf21kf+E/vhvKWbbb7IEWHFNuQGATCAG+WX529rMQ83l9KsDB9d
    G9gRo0Hsw7CK2D56wv7m22ur6QeaCgZNF7xHEECxZkaT9jlI9JFLU8pSXaFvSEcC
    YgqKlm2b+zs0Q4mW8mH89xiQ=
Received: (qmail 23888 invoked by uid 1000); 21 Mar 2020 15:33:12 -0000
X-AntiVirus: Clean
Message-ID: <20200321153311.23887.qmail@gt-van-cus5.nmsrv.com>
From: x@x.com
To: support@mysite.co.uk
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?d2ViZm9ybSA=?=
Date: Sat, 21 Mar 2020 08:33:11 -0700
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="15848047911.6F3Ff.23881"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Spam-Score: 16
X-Spam-Bar: +
X-Spam-Report: Spam detection software, running on the system "admin.foo.com",
 has NOT identified this incoming email as spam.  The original
 message has been attached to this so you can view it or label
 similar future email.  If you have any questions, see
 @@CONTACT_ADDRESS@@ for details.

 Content preview:  Date: Sat, 21 Mar 2020 08:33:11 -0700 MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type:
    multipart/alternative; boundary="15848047910.05Ba9cd88.23881" [...] 

 Content analysis details:   (1.6 points, 4.0 required)

  pts rule name              description
 ---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
 -0.0 SPF_HELO_PASS          SPF: HELO matches SPF record
  1.1 TRACKER_ID             BODY: Incorporates a tracking ID number
  0.0 T_TVD_MIME_NO_HEADERS  BODY: No description available.
  0.5 T_DKIM_INVALID         DKIM-Signature header exists but is not valid
  0.0 T_MIME_MALF            Malformed MIME: headers in body





--15848047911.6F3Ff.23881

Date: Sat, 21 Mar 2020 08:33:11 -0700

MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="15848047910.05Ba9cd88.23881"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit





--15848047910.05Ba9cd88.23881

Date: Sat, 21 Mar 2020 08:33:11 -0700

MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Content-Disposition: inline

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable



foo bar=



--15848047910.05Ba9cd88.23881

Date: Sat, 21 Mar 2020 08:33:11 -0700

MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

Content-Disposition: inline

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable



some message=



--15848047910.05Ba9cd88.23881--



--15848047911.6F3Ff.23881

Date: Sat, 21 Mar 2020 08:33:11 -0700

MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="logo.jpg"

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="logo.jpg"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64



/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYF

BgYGBwkIBgcJBwYGCAsICQoKCgoKBggLDAsKDAkKCgr/2wBDAQICAgICAgUDAwUKBwYHCgoKCgoK

CgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgr/wgARCAAlAPwDAREA

AhEBAxEB/8QAHAABAAMBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAUGBwgDBAIB/8QAFgEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAEC/9oADAMBAAIQAxAAAAHv4AHkeoAAAAAAAAAAAAABQk9yCNTWmpclpyXBYFPqII/hJkisen1H

4XySbX4SQK0kysSkqtUS5r6gAGfJRCxGnLxgx2c3x6z1cvLadBrnSWFcoTb1whOg1w9NeXyINN0a

yBPpMmTq1rgq47GmrkoAEWex+CQKelxWnJcVyxNTWLP0eJ9JnaamuWJqajIU0hfjSfWLSXXMksZa

lAAAAAAAAAAAEWSgABREvagD/8QAJRAAAgICAgEDBQEAAAAAAAAABQYDBAIHAAEgEhVACBARExQi

/9oACAEBAAEFAvCWaGDH5rm3WwcysHdB1zcn+UXljYKVUZeHtgpauT5K0rkGIc4FYadZmmne0Bmt

NyuzNIFOEiydEyOlaVyDEOcCsNOQ+FhuhGdcZcPXj6qJQeTy41toFJD0L9MpSItyuIrjyFEtScNj

pyH1DLHYi8WxUt3Sy9slnuOG9c/16ltyW8aCiMoi1OhLcmHjwdYrdVCJIsu3Li4P23rtQuKw5irO

Frd+j4PbVnb5Wdj2Npm1/Vq25cXB+29dqFxWHbEsKNDc+u1QvQt7QDE48dDFomETzaFyvTOaQwtY

6vmXsLf1N4YYRYNlqbYEeu7mZFB8TAQQw0R40cJqlRIw4P66/HBev0sMb5nr9LkZOJNDKN457KM9

6HiBorPpfCdGxwygIqJNDKN45ToZZ7m+2lYIYlTEGKwNsimuN9SOOOGPsCH7O82rkND61Rw8y+mf

IDhhgCj4lNdgTbJ4f//EAB4RAAEEAgMBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAEDFBIFARQEJx/9oACAEDAQE/AdId

AYw+tbWgjKEK2tig4hemlDrW4yMaDjH/xAAUEQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABw/9oACAECAQE/ASD/

xAA9EAABAwIEAgUKBAQHAAAAAAABAgMEBREABhIhEzEQFCJBYRUgMjNCUVJxkaEWJDSBBxdAgiNU

YnKSosH/2gAIAQEABj8C8zU86lAJABUbb/10Og0CniZVqkoiGwtVkISn0nXD3IT9+WJUnNWcW6i2

8EdXjtU9LKY59qxuSq/jhyXb9NUIT3ytJbv9uhOT5OZIyKku2mKVb3PIe6/hz6GKNmDMcaLJk+qa

dVv8z8I8T0TFya3GaTAcCJqnXQkMq0hViT4HHlChVWPMYvbixngtN/dtiXlAxUhEemMykO33UVrW

m3/XDNbnQ0R3y680+y2u6UqbcUg2P9uF1zMlRRGjINitQJufcANycMVamSA7HktBxlwe0ki4OJi5

NbjNJgOBE1TroSGVaQqxJ8DjyhQqrHmMXtxYzwWm/u2w/Tn6myh6Mwl6Qha7cNs3AUfDY4W7l6ux

JyWjZwxZCV6fnbGjUL25YfRAlpdMV8syAn2HAAdJ/Yj69Cq9mSbwIyFhJXoKtzyFhhqpU6Sl5h9s

LZdQdlJPI4flVPMENhuK6GpCnJCRw1kXCT42N7YbqVNlIfYeTqadbVdKh7xhv8T1cMKd3QhLSlqt

8Vkg2HjhL7K9SFp1JUO8edHzfRMwIp0+FHWzxJDAdZW0oglKxcd6RuCMR8sCRRq60tR65LoiXUiG

Lc1k6kc9rar4rS72tGTY+OtOHHqewl18NEstrXpClW2BPdj+ZWe5ztSqEusvPU+hNdkOzg6pscu0

4bp2vskd2GXqhFSzIUykvMpc1BC7bpv379+M1Z9/i1Vy1GYq3V5FIjq7D3CSlTber0ljtJskWuRf

EWpVajeT33m9SoXE1cIeyDsN7W27sZjDmXX65XFTGfJNKtdpH5du7yr9lPcNR3HdiRIrMlt6pVKS

ZNQUwnS2lZFghA+FIAGHIOU6hGhh/LDXW5j7WtTaeO56Cb7q+e2Khl4yXHTTK/MjFx09pX+JqufE

hQP74GUIZDsmNETHpcRX+akA6pB8GmhfwJxRDaxbhBlQ9ymyUH7pxmMOZdfrlcVMZ8k0q12kfl27

vKv2U9w1Hcd2JEisyW3qlUpJk1BTCdLaVkWCED4UgAYU/mimyak4qiR/J1HYbKxLe4rtrp5G3+rY

Ym5xzQyyxUamlCeoxfVw2U+g1f2jvcn34h5/y22pdRoSlOdXST+Zjn1rXzsLjxGK/mOPfgz8zyXo

+oWPD0thP2GLYyq7UHEojN1pbrqlnYaYzpBxS1ym9HFS462j4W1urUgf8SMKgVAcaEqD5TTFcF0c

XhhnVbv5YDbaAlI5ADljMojkqeb63Kq7lv00aNrTGjf3LTxCMUSc76TtJjqV8+GPOVTK5TmpUdRB

Uy+jUk23G2EwaVAZjMoHYaYbCEj9hhylViC1JjO+sYeRdKt74sMPZkpmXY7U19RK5ATc3PO1/Rv4

dH4vcy7HVUdj1lSb7/Fblq8efRm2pOxCjjVFhLbikW1pTGb5HvF+j8Q9UT13qvV+P38LVq0/XEhy

nxEtGXIL8kp9twgDV9AMHMgpTHXyzwjL4fb0e6+BApkRDDIUpQbbFhdSio/ck4zbUnYhRxqiwltx

SLa0pjN8j3i/RPqa4h0t5ejttvFG1+M6SAfp0ynI7SUNu1ycpCUjYDjqH/mF5jTEHXXIwYU/c+rB

vp93PDcHMtIamNNPB1tt3kFDvwGmkBKUiyUpGwGBmY09HXxG6uJPtcK+rT9ejMD/AAmmjKpzzZKU

gF11aNCfmSSMUqhyfWRKey05/uCBf+pFNpEQMsJWpQQCealFRO/iT5zOZau9MkqjLC2IbstRjIWO

Sw3yv5v/xAAjEAEBAAIBBAIDAQEAAAAAAAABEQAhMRBBUWEggUCRoXHh/9oACAEBAAE/IfgAOFMK

YG+6/nIRrucE3YE42kHNJXtnSOgEklqTBJpoeD1/XSYiXZ4qyHSNqkOhSWGahYQIiIQGYIlHFyCW

YCKGh+8ELj10c0nfrKzpDoJHgn9uO7OFZcbR2+8Ci5MJwAq8AuA0L9DTB2ae+LkEswEUND94IXHr

o5pO/WEwWlZQOhP6s3e46bwVZiJdtF7Tzj3Kp2weyr6dJ/cxy8AVf+OW8WyMoPswJ4TgTdaYdyOG

bueb4Q5MluujaxTlUK1Wc4NwLhEKPysLT0XypsCR74w0kIYVGWo0H0w93ehaX9mc6iP7oLCwsZhs

+tmmiEKKpf2tsU9wSkko0LLMibbeixJp0W4NhuVyKKtHkTGym5cRsNe5TsGqWA9sl/uuh2EELtle

cTaumWYyFX0cvYd4TrpwfugYQFcTGPeFqox5afQmB/SGI2Gvcp2DVLAe2S/3XQ7CCF2yvOayUhBP

DYp3C7QzSQtm7gPK4ataN8ZVwXNZyuJdM5xU2ubRQPMMpdt+MCjQ4dovjbiHk/P8RjPL0BmMbjY3

Lw8YcIZOB6MpWi1ojKaVknFxSuMfO/8AfkRT/iVsXMQcm8MOfoAMJOoESAUfCD/pgCEDgMVjbgVr

sllWS3fRWvNEpAAmYA14c9Gy2rUDYdxxq3p+1jfQLJz4uUF3DuFe0X1kMjyue+aZLUO0QZ7Y9uNl

tWoGw7jjVvTuZ43Ip5mweusdw8oeAcAThI2x0pMWNl4uAGsFQkNHelJw3eAP/IC0AdjKoLldn6vL

pWVgaImcZecZS/5Sn9X8lD2NhuEl2z7+Xcl07XGT5875+P8A/9oADAMBAAIAAwAAABAACAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAC2CgwmmwmUAWGGAAAoDzHVpDVJOLaGgAASQggAQQAAYUEagAAAAAAAAAAAQAAEAD/xAAe

EQEAAwEAAgMBAAAAAAAAAAABABExECAhQEFRUP/aAAgBAwEBPxD+EtQH7mOWXXFDlkEcl+6g2RQL

ZssgjkuCOeCgW8smxQ3zT7ILdTTgereVasGSy37AqN5noVPakwllv2BUa3AdYPsjsXjpwrh9Gewe

SDMm8oHlF3w18KL4a+LHEHeUXfNIFFfJAPJC+P8A/8QAHxEAAQQCAgMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAQMUER

ICFQMEBx/9oACAECAQE/EO7xnwidPjU3GEUIRlU1OXKpgj61OdhPS//EACIQAQEAAgIDAQACAwAA

AAAAAAERACExQRBRYSBAgXGRsf/aAAgBAQABPxD8GOqCGGoFAByqB/OPH/B4VagA7/4FaJ9GyzEC

DtVzXq5/wcyv+B8IsJR0tAlQAEQTwjCRqY4iAFiBUcBGRKI84tH66YgpP3sjkTJgUoUqGBpVspre

GIQrSLsKIm1p1kOUEEqIlOgyesaSrxOb+BJgWQUB4qkQASgMAnCDi0frpiCk/eyORMmBShSoYGlW

ymt5pgsATvmGrrlKUSYQ6JeQoKWUNXAwHOMiCDlBSv094tufqI8mjC9J34S1Qiez+tdGhGAuAciq

XluRB/vLAUZKY0SlsCE3non9GEEnsy28ljIWFQIgCoM4SUaOB8RH+/0BgpMchciwtlw0tr0D32ii

6c2qy0pOh/eD7jy6BHIY90MCsZMkK1lQbA9FsaXHMNt0CHkOk0LMC05dU0pMjUg2T/heSz467TtB

G8bAGLFmBgK87LI+HNeUM0tC4CQK7ZhA2dBcDnLWb44AlQFamEshj3wKNb1GiuE+L3ygv1N9HAje

NgDFizAwFedlkfDmvKGaWgriDVeC5uul8E8eAZeSgbN6AhOB78gA4msoyhIuGSnARObjZHTTrOu6

Xbc940SHQoGhSC8IZX+byWmuAgaAA0GHpsP65R2J54Vwx+SxnAGg+GOSMlrIkOCNtjwHYW/gqz/t

+gKzELpQQi9mB14XkQDhDowVY+nkcjH+gTZgcoABAPWKqa4ABRbBNNK+HFHCFbICRMg0Dwp0gaUk

CDOzDsPiobCLn2z0QvkDcJgXUYDduu5pDXVqn6bSMQ1xfRzAdAYXGyQ84792K4p0gaUkCDOzDsPi

qde9slEbBY1yeEEiYCoJ52jQAA0AGX00fP8AOAcQLVUAI6G5jICKyoICawxhDSAE0AABoDGkYRiF

JsZzSisQW4PYQGSoEF2pQy9VWENTnRMfP5IxEHpTIFrXlda/QTK7xRzsZE5Bh/P/2Q==



--15848047911.6F3Ff.23881--
```

The *really* weird part - is that the EXACT same code sends fine from one of my other servers. Yet, the MIME headers all look the same (minus having different part ids and date stamps obviously :)). I've got the host looking into this - in case its an Exim issue on their end, rather than my code. Seems very odd though!

Comment: Strange. Can you please add the source code of the mail which was actually received by Outlook and not the one you've intended to send? Maybe something got mangled on the way.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks - yes very odd indeed! The most frustrating part, is that the exact same code works to the exact same email addy, when sent from my other server! I've uploaded the contents of the email from the destination account in the OP. Thanks

Comment: That's not the same mail but has much more parts than your code generated. It is impossible to tell what's going on if code, sample output and real mail don't match at all. Anyway, it looks like it got blocked as spam and that the Antispam solution caused the strange output by attempting to include the original mail but failing to do so in a user friendly way.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich sorry yes, that one was a more complicated one I was testing (with attachments). Regarding the \r\n yes that seems the same in both (the one that works, and also the one that doesn't). It seems to render. I thought that was the issue to start with - but seeing as both have the same line breaks, and one works, it seems odd. I'm just getting the host to update all the related Perl modules in case (on a long shot!) that is the problem. Will keep you posted

Comment: @SteffenUllrich well very odd. They updated `IO::All` to v0.87 and `Email::Sender` to v1.300034. ... and would you believe it, that fixed it! Must have been a bug in one of those that was fixed later on. Man what a stress that was!